# Mongodb database Schema design tips

Tags: java, mongodb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mongodb database Schema Design with shared data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239045/mongodb-database-schema-design-with-shared-data)

Hi I am newbie to mongodb.I am using java.

I have 4 tables Tenant,system,authorization in my relational table.

Something like this.

```
Table            Fields

 Tenant           Tenant_ID(PK), Tenant_INFO
 System           System_ID(PK), System_Info
 Authorization    System_ID, Autho_Info.
 System_prop      System_ID, Prop_Info, Tenant_ID
```

In System_prop table, Tenant_ID refers the Tenant Table Tenant_ID (PK), System_ID refers the System Table System_ID.

In Authorization table, System_ID refers System tabel System_ID

I am switching my database from relational to mongodb. First thing I need to do is Schema design.

Query I need to do is:

```
SELECT D.Prop_Info, D.System_ID, A.Tenant_Info From TENANT A ,System_prop D, SYSTEM B, Where D.System_ID = B.System_ID AND D.Tenant_ID = A.Tenant_ID

SELECT C.System_ID, C.auth_Info, B.System_ID FROM Authorization C, SYSTEM B WHERE C.System_ID = B.System_ID
```

Can anyone help me how to design these tables as collections in mongodb?

Do i need to embed r use dbref? Help me to design the schema for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the schema information you provided, it looks like you have a many-to-many relationship between Tenant and System (through the JOIN table System_prop), and a one-to-many relationship between System and Authorization.

In MongoDB, both of these types of relationships can be implemented using array fields. This is how you could set up your System collection:

```
{
    System_Info: ...,

    Tenant: [ 
        { 
            Tenant_Id: ..., 
            Tenant_Info: ..., 
            Prop_Info: ...
        }, 
        { 
            Tenant_Id: ..., 
            Tenant_Info: ..., 
            Prop_Info: ...
        } ],

    Authorization: [ 
        {
            Auth_Id: ..., 
            Auth_Info: ...
        }, 
        {
            Auth_Id: ..., 
            Auth_Info: ...
        } ]
}
```

However, for the Tenant info, you will now have de-normalized duplicate information, i.e. the same Tenant document appears in different System documents. It is up to your application to ensure consistency.

As for the queries you mentioned: It looks like there is some information missing. For the first query, you're joining on the `Tenant_Id` but not requesting any information from the Tenant table. The second one requests `Prop_Info` from the Authorization table but that table doesn't have `Prop_Info`. Should that be `A.Autho_Info` instead? So you might want to double-check these queries.

Here are some additional resources about schema design in MongoDB that are worth a read:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design

https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/designing-mongodb-schemas-with-embedded-non-embedded-and-bucket-structures

In the end, it depends on your application and most frequent queries how exactly you choose to store your data, and the example above is just one way to set up your schema.

Comment: yes, I have edited the queries now.kindly,Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You are still thinking in relational databases. MongoDB, however, is a document-oriented database.

1. artificial ID numbers are usually not needed, because every document automatically has a _id field, which is a GUID (as good as guaranteed to be globally unique).
2. relation tables should not be used in MongoDB. n-type relations are made with arrays fields instead. So when 1 system has N authorizations it uses, your system document should have a field "authorization" which is an array of the object IDs of the authorizations it has. Yes, that would be a horrible violation of the normalization rules of relational databases. But you don't have a relational database here. In MongoDB it is practical to represent N-relations with arrays, because arrays are transparent to the query language.